# Where are my files when using Gitlab docker build

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm using gitlab CI to build docker image

```
image: docker:latest

services:
    - docker:dind

stages:
    - build

build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - docker build -t image/name .
```

However, I don't know **where can I find my files from the repository** in that image. Do I have to copy them somehow or I just missed their location?

I tried searching for the files using `docker run image/name ls`.

I can't find any mention about it in docs nor the internet.

EDIT: MY dockerfile for now contains only `FROM debian:stretch`

Comment: could you also post your Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes, I added the mention about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is your Dockerfile, nothing happens. You have no [`ADD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) or [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) commands. Use them to add stuff to your image.

Also I recommend the https://docs.docker.com/get-started/ guide and this section to get your head around the concept: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#define-a-container-with-a-dockerfile

Comment: Ah ok, forgot to add those :/. I was using dockerfile with docker-compose before so there was no need for these. Thanks!